# Editing background-color of Text Input Fields Without Changing Their Default Browser Styling

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have some thoughts on my head that involves changing the `background-color` of some text input fields I have. I went ahead to see if they'd look as I hoped, and this is what I saw:

[image: background-color for text input]

First one being truly plain, second one being with the CSS styling `background-color: #FFFFFF;` and the last one has `background-color: #FEFEFE;` which you can experience yourself there: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fL1boy0/)

It seems to be that browsers are dismissing all their pre-set styles for the input elements, as soon as I change this style property. Internet Explorer 11 even gives up on the blue glow which is normally present when a text input field is hovered (should also be on blur).

Is it possible for me to change just the background colour without causing all that?

I probably will just thoroughly style the text input fields anyway, I'm asking it out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research about this, its something that makes me wonder what its the real behavior, unfortunately, I couldn't find any explanation to this, so I can only assume, that once you style an input, the appearance of the same, its reset to a default value, ignoring the native styles that the browser is giving to the element.

I think you probably know this already, because of your last comment, but just in case, this will help you keep the blur effect on the inputs, and at the same time, it will make them render in the same way for different browsers, you can also add height to that, to keep it even more consistent.

```
input
{
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
input:focus
{
    box-shadow:0 0 3px 0 blue;
    outline:none;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

I hope this helps!